# ROKU: open another Scene/Screen from a screen

Tags: roku, brightscript

With the use of Task inside a Scene, we got response from a api. But how to access the response of Task from main.brs?

Can we change the scene from a scene in a scenegraph?
I could not figure that. Or can we only change the scene from main.brs?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

If your scene has the response as a string variable you can pass values using the interface fields in the xml file. You can try doing something like this.

In Scene.brs

```
  m.top.response = response
```

In Scene.xml

```
<interface>
  <field id="Response" type="String" alias="m.top.response" />
</interface>
```

then later on in your main.brs

```
m.sampleScene = m.top.FindNode("Scene")]
print(m.sampleScene.response)
```

Comment: Mind to share how to actually transition between scenes? Like open scene B from a button push in scene A.

Comment: i did by using the task node is it good method or what can anyon explain?